# Blockchain development bootcamp

Tags: contract-deployment, javascript

[image]

I'm facing an issue in deploying a smart contract on the blockchain

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'args')
at main (/mnt/d/Practice/LEarn/BlockChain/Trading/blockchain-developer-bootcamp/scripts/2_seed-exchange.js:102:30)
```

following is the file which is causing error

```
require("truffle-test-utils").init();
const config = require("../src/config.json");

const tokens = (n) => {
return ethers.utils.parseUnits(n.toString(), "ether");
};

const wait = (seconds) => {
const milliseconds = seconds * 1000;
return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, milliseconds));
};

async function main() {
// Fetch accounts from wallet - these are unlocked
const accounts = await ethers.getSigners();

// Fetch network
const { chainId } = await ethers.provider.getNetwork();
console.log("Using chainId:", chainId);

// Fetch deployed tokens
const DApp = await ethers.getContractAt(
  "Token",
  config[chainId].DApp.address
);
console.log(`Dapp Token fetched: ${DApp.address}\n`);

const mETH = await ethers.getContractAt(
  "Token",
  config[chainId].mETH.address
);
console.log(`mETH Token fetched: ${mETH.address}\n`);

const mDAI = await ethers.getContractAt(
  "Token",
  config[chainId].mDAI.address
);
console.log(`mDAI Token fetched: ${mDAI.address}\n`);

// Fetch the deployed exchange
const exchange = await ethers.getContractAt(
  "Exchange",
  config[chainId].exchange.address
);
console.log(`Exchange fetched: ${exchange.address}\n`);

// Give tokens to account[1]
const sender = accounts[0];
const receiver = accounts[1];
let amount = tokens(10000);

// user1 transfers 10,000 mETH...
let transaction, result;
transaction = await mETH.connect(sender).transfer(receiver.address, amount);
console.log(
  `Transferred ${amount} tokens from ${sender.address} to ${receiver.address}\n`
);

// Set up exchange users
const user1 = accounts[0];
const user2 = accounts[1];
amount = tokens(10000);

// user1 approves 10,000 Dapp...
transaction = await DApp.connect(user1).approve(exchange.address, amount);
await transaction.wait();
console.log(`Approved ${amount} tokens from ${user1.address}`);

// user1 deposits 10,000 DApp...
transaction = await exchange
  .connect(user1)
  .depositToken(DApp.address, amount);
await transaction.wait();
console.log(`Deposited ${amount} Ether from ${user1.address}\n`);

// User 2 Approves mETH
transaction = await mETH.connect(user2).approve(exchange.address, amount);
await transaction.wait();
console.log(`Approved ${amount} tokens from ${user2.address}`);

// User 2 Deposits mETH
transaction = await exchange
  .connect(user2)
  .depositToken(mETH.address, amount);
await transaction.wait();
console.log(`Deposited ${amount} tokens from ${user2.address}\n`);

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Seed a Cancelled Order
//

// User 1 makes order to get tokens
let orderId;
transaction = await exchange
  .connect(user1)
  .makeOrder(mETH.address, tokens(100), DApp.address, tokens(5));
result = await transaction.wait();
console.log(`Made order from ${user1.address}`);

// User 1 cancels order
orderId = result.events[0].args.id;
transaction = await exchange.connect(user1).cancelOrder(orderId);
result = await transaction.wait();
console.log(`Cancelled order from ${user1.address}\n`);

// Wait 1 second
await wait(1);

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Seed Filled Orders
//

// User 1 makes order
transaction = await exchange
  .connect(user1)
  .makeOrder(mETH.address, tokens(100), DApp.address, tokens(10));
result = await transaction.wait();
console.log(`Made order from ${user1.address}`);

// User 2 fills order
orderId = result.events[0].args.id; // <= error
transaction = await exchange.connect(user2).fillOrder(orderId);
result = await transaction.wait();
console.log(`Filled order from ${user1.address}\n`);

// Wait 1 second
await wait(1);

// User 1 makes another order
transaction = await exchange.makeOrder(
  mETH.address,
  tokens(50),
  DApp.address,
  tokens(15)
);
result = await transaction.wait();
console.log(`Made order from ${user1.address}`);

// User 2 fills another order
orderId = result.events[0].args.id;
transaction = await exchange.connect(user2).fillOrder(orderId);
result = await transaction.wait();
console.log(`Filled order from ${user1.address}\n`);

// Wait 1 second
await wait(1);

// User 1 makes final order
transaction = await exchange
  .connect(user1)
  .makeOrder(mETH.address, tokens(200), DApp.address, tokens(20));
result = await transaction.wait();
console.log(`Made order from ${user1.address}`);

// User 2 fills final order
orderId = result.events[0].args.id;
transaction = await exchange.connect(user2).fillOrder(orderId);
result = await transaction.wait();
console.log(`Filled order from ${user1.address}\n`);

// Wait 1 second
await wait(1);
// three orders upto now

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Seed Open Orders
//

// User 1 makes 10 orders
for (let i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
  transaction = await exchange
    .connect(user1)
    .makeOrder(mETH.address, tokens(10 * i), DApp.address, tokens(10));
  result = await transaction.wait();

  console.log(`Made order from ${user1.address}`);

  // Wait 1 second
  await wait(1);
}

// User 2 makes 10 orders
for (let i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
  transaction = await exchange
    .connect(user2)
    .makeOrder(DApp.address, tokens(10), mETH.address, tokens(10 * i));
  result = await transaction.wait();

  console.log(`Made order from ${user2.address}`);

  // Wait 1 second
  await wait(1);
}
}

main()
.then(() => process.exit(0))
.catch((error) => {
  console.error(error);
  process.exit(1);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see your smart contract but looks like that function `makeOrder` doesn't emit an event. To check this you can check it directly in the smart contract or before the error line just run `console.log(result.events)` and look at the returned data.